# Multiclass with logreg

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

So i'm trying to find a simple (not Dijkstra's algorithm) for a shortest path problem.

Without reproducing everything, I have 3 paths and 50 samples of it (i.e. shape (50,3))and I have identified the shortest path for each sample using the min. function

```
for x_train being 

newx_train = np.zeros((50,3))
newx_train[:,0] = p1_train
newx_train[:,1] = p2_train
newx_train[:,2] = p3_train
[x_train] <- just random numbers generated
and subsequently, y_train (since I'm generating it; i pass min function through it)


newy_train[np.arange(newx_train.shape[0]),newx_train.argmin(axis=1)]=1
print(newy_train)

[newy_train] <- passing min will show a 1 for each row where the minimum value is

So i get something like 
[[1,0,0],
 [0,1,0],
 [1,0,0],
 [0,0,1]]
```

Based on x_train, y_train generated, I am trying to implement SVM, logreg to predict how well they perform for multi-class and then i'll compute the classification matrix and accuracy.

My question is, how do i go about using multi-class for logreg? When i run a fit through x_train, y_train; understandably python throws up error that y should be 1-D array but got (50,3) instead.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
LogReg = LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs', multi_class = 'multinomial')
    LogReg.fit(newx_train,newy_train[:,0])
    ylog_pred = LogReg.predict(newx_test)
    print(ylog_pred)
```

The above code naturally works for binary (assuming only 2 paths) since predicting '1' for one column (index 0) would naturally mean the other column is a '0'. But this would not work for multi-class. Could anyone help with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just missing the part with how to interpret the `y`.

`LogisticRegression` expects the `y` column to not be one-hot encoded and to actually be the target labels, so you need something like

```
newy_train = np.argmax(newy_train, axis=1) # index of max across each row
```

Then you should be able to fit something with

```
LogReg.fit(newx_train,newy_train)
```